# mysql update query (containing 'where' syntax) not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like this (sql):

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `silver_and_pgm` (
>     `_metal_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
>     `_bid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
>     `_change` varchar(30) NOT NULL
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> --
>
> ### -- Dumping data for table `silver_and_pgm`
>
> INSERT INTO `silver_and_pgm` (`_metal_name`, `_bid`, `_change`) VALUES
>   ('Silver\r\n', '555', '-0.22\r\n'),
>   ('Platinum\r\n', '555', '-9.00\r\n'),
>   ('Palladium\r\n', '555', '0.00\r\n'),
>   ('Rhodium\r\n', '555', '0.00\r\n');

and i am using the following code to update a row which contains metal_name as Silver

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "1234";
$database = "kitco";
$con=mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$bid = '101010';
$metal_name = 'Silver';

$query = "update silver_and_pgm set _bid='$bid' where _metal_name='$metal_name'";
//$query2 = "update silver_and_pgm set _bid='444'";;
echo $query."<br>";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)echo "error";

?>
```

but $query doesn't work . it works fine if I use $query2 . If I use the same query directly in SQL of phpmyadmin result is same.
what is the problem with $query . I think its correct.
Would anybody please find the bug ??

Comment: your matel_name values contain \r\n as the part of the matel_name so the exact match **_matel_name='Silver'** won't search the specific record to update, if all the matel_name follows the same pattern you can also use the **like**, pls see my ans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a line break in your _metal_name in the database, the SQL query says `Silver\r\n`.